# Proof verification: $T\in\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{P}(\bf{R}))$ being injective and $\deg Tp\leq\deg p$ implies $T$ is surjective and $\deg Tp=\deg p$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations

**Notations**: $\mathcal P(\mathbf R)$ denotes the polynomials with real coefficients, while $\mathcal{L}(\mathcal P(\mathbf R))$ denotes the linear transformations within $\mathcal P(\mathbf R)$ with respect to the field of real numbers. Also, $\mathcal P_m(\mathbf R)$ denotes the polynomials with real coefficient and degree less than or equal to $m$.

---

Are the proofs to the following propositions Correct ?

**Theorem.** Given that $T\in\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{R}))$ is injective and that $\deg Tp\leq\deg p$ for all $p\in\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{R})$ such that $p$ is a non-zero polynomial then

$a)$ $T$ is surjective

*Proof.* Let $p$ be arbitrary non-zero polynomial. We may assume without loss of generality that $\deg p = m$ where $m\in\{0,1,2,3,...\}$

Let us now examine the function $T|_{\mathcal{P}_m\mathbf{(R)}}$. The proposition $\forall p\in\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{R})(\deg Tp\leq\deg p)$ together with $T\in\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{P}\mathbf{(R)})$ implies that $T|_{\mathcal{P}_m\mathbf{(R)}}\in\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{P}_m\mathbf{(R)})$, moreover the injectivity of $T$ implies the the injectivity  of $T|_{\mathcal{P}_m\mathbf{(R)}}$ and since injectivity and surjectivity are equivalent for linear operators defined on a finite-dimensional vector space it follows that $T|_{\mathcal{P}_m\mathbf{(R)}}$ is surjective, consequently $\exists q\in \mathcal{P(\mathbf{R})}(Tq=p)$.

$\blacksquare$

$b)$ $\deg Tp=\deg p$ for all non zero polynomial $p\in\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{R})$

*Proof.* We prove the above propostion by recourse to *Mathematical-Induction*.

*Basis-Step:* Let $p$ be an arbitrary polynomial with $\deg p=0$ ($p$ is non-zero) we know that $\forall p\in\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{R})(\deg Tp\leq\deg p)$ thus in particular $\deg Tp\leq \deg p$.

Now assume for the purpose of contradiction that $\deg Tp<\deg p$ which implies that $\deg Tp = -\infty$ but since $T$ is injective and therefore $\operatorname{null}T=\{0\}$ it must be that $p=0$ a contradiction consequently $\deg Tp=\deg p=0$.

*Inductive Step:* Assume that $k$ is arbitrary and that $\deg Tp=\deg p$ where $\deg p\in\{0,1,2,3,...,k\}$.

Consider now an arbitrary polynomial $q$ such that $\deg q=k+1$ assume further that $Tq=r$ and that $\deg r<\deg q$ therefore $\deg r\leq k$ since $T$ is surjective it follows that for some $s\in\mathcal{P(\mathbf{R})}$, $Ts=r$ and by inductive hypothesis $\deg s = \deg r \leq k$ but $Ts=r=Tq$ and $s\neq q$ contradicting the fact that $T$ is injective therefore it must be that $\deg q=\deg r$.

$\blacksquare$

Comment: What a terrible choice of notation for the polynomial ring. The standard notation is simply $\Bbb R[x]$ and $\Bbb R_{\leq m}[x]$. Whereas $\cal P(\Bbb R)$ is almost universally interpreted as the power set of the reals.

Comment: Sorry about that Its because of the text book i am using

Comment: I see. That's a damn shame.

Comment: @AsafKaragila and $\operatorname{Hom}$ instead of $\mathcal L$?

Comment: @Kenny: That I actually saw used relatively frequently in the case of vector spaces, $L(V)=\operatorname{Hom}(V,V)$. But I agree that it can be *very* confusing to read this notation.

Comment: Since you have put the `proof-verification` tag to your question, please do not edit your proof in a way that would invalidate any "verification" answers. If you do want any edit, please keep the original version and add the new version under your old one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`proof-verification (for one of the many edited versions of your proof):`

> **Theorem.** Given that $T\in\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{R}))$ is injective and that $\deg Tp\leq\deg p$ for all $p\in\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{R})$ such that $p$ is a non-zero polynomial then
>
> $a)$ $T$ is surjective
>
> *Proof.* Let $p$ `(One could choose another notation so that it would not be confused with the free variable p used later.)` be arbitrary non-zero polynomial. We may assume without loss of generality that $\deg p = m$ where $m\in\{0,1,2,3,...\}.$ Let us now examine the function $T|_{\mathcal{P}_m\mathbf{(R)}}$. The <s>`proposition`</s> `assumption` $$
> \forall p\in\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{R})(\deg Tp\leq\deg p)
> $$ 
>   together with $T\in\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{P}\mathbf{(R)})$ implies that $T|_{\mathcal{P}_m\mathbf{(R)}}\in\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{P}_m\mathbf{(R)})$; moreover the injectivity of $T$ implies the the injectivity  of $T|_{\mathcal{P}_m\mathbf{(R)}}$ and since injectivity and surjectivity are equivalent for linear operators defined on a finite-dimensional vector space it follows that $T|_{\mathcal{P}_m\mathbf{(R)}}$ is surjective, consequently 
>   $$
> \exists q\in \mathcal{P(\mathbf{R})}(Tq=p).
> $$
>
> $b)$ $\deg Tp=\deg p$ for all non zero polynomial $p\in\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{R})$.
>
> *Proof.* We prove the above propostion by recourse to *mathematical induction*.
>
> *Basis-Step:* Let $p$ `(Again, another notation would be better.)` be an arbitrary polynomial with $\deg p=0$ ($p$ is non-zero) we know `by assumptions` that $\forall p\in\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{R})(\deg Tp\leq\deg p)$ thus in particular $\deg Tp\leq \deg p$. `(One can guess though, notations are confusing.)`
>
> Now assume for the purpose of contradiction that $\deg Tp<\deg p$ which implies that $\deg Tp = -\infty$ `(This is OK if you have defined that the zero polynomisl has degree` $-\infty$`.)` but since $T$ is injective and therefore $\operatorname{null}T=\{0\}$ it must be that $p=0$ a contradiction consequently $\deg Tp=\deg p=0$. `(Isn't 0 the only polynomial with degree` $-\infty$ `? Why would you need the injectivity of T to make such conclusion?)`
>
> *Inductive Step:* Assume that $k$ is arbitrary and that $\deg Tp=\deg p$ where $\deg p\in\{0,1,2,3,...,k\}.$
>
> Consider now an arbitrary polynomial $q$ such that $\deg q=k+1$ assume further that $Tq=r$ and that $\deg r<\deg q$ therefore $\deg r\leq k$ since $T$ is surjective it follows that for some $s\in\mathcal{P(\mathbf{R})}$, $Ts=r$ and by inductive hypothesis $\deg s = \deg r \leq k$ `(and thus` $s\neq q$`)`but $Ts=r=Tq$ <s>`and $s\neq q$`</s>, contradicting the fact that $T$ is injective therefore it must be that $\deg q=\deg r$.

Answer (score 1):

For part $b)$, the degree of $k$ needs to be able to be zero, or else your induction would not be able to prove that the proposition is true for $p$ with degree $1$. You only proved that $P(0)$ is true and that $P(1) \implies P(2)$ etc. without proving that $P(0) \implies P(1)$, where $P$ is the proposition allegedly proved using the induction. Apart from this pedantry, you also need more ink explaining how $\deg r < \deg q$ implies $\deg q = k$. (Actually, you can only say that $\deg q \le k$.)

Comment: for part $a)$ is the condition that $p$ was arbitrary not sufficient to show surjectivity

Comment: @AtifFarooq sorry, I misread.

Comment: for part $b)$ why can i only say that $\deg q\leq k$ i have no idea why this is the case ?

Comment: Disregard my note in parentheses for now, and explain how $\deg r < \deg q$ implies $\deg q = k$.

Comment: OK yes i now realize my mistake yes i am clearly an imbecile

Answer (score 1):

There are problems with the final paragraph. As you have already been told, all you can say about $q$ is that $\deg q\leqslant k$. Besides, how do you reach a contradiction here? It is more simple to say that, since $\deg q\leqslant k$, it follows from what you have already proved that $q=Ts$ for some polynomial $s$ whose degree is also smaller than or equal to $k$. But then $s\neq p$ and therefore $T$ would not be injective.